# jquery get/getJSON: call a function after *several* files load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have a jquery page that loads parts stored in several external files. I need to execute a function, but only after *all* of the get and getJSON callbacks have triggered.

Is there a good way to do this?

At the moment, I'm to nesting all of the get commands inside each other. The code is ugly, and worse, the gets are executed one after another, leading to slowdown on page loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using >= jQuery 1.5, you can use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when($.getJSON('/test1'), $.getJSON('/test2')).done(function(result1, result2) {
  console.log(result1[0]); //result1 is an array of the response values from test1
  console.log(result2[0]);
});
```

The `.done` function will only execute after all ajax calls are successful.  There is also a `.then` method than can take success and failure functions.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count/log of responses.

```
var received_responses = 0;
function is_done() {
   received_responses++;
   if (received_responses == 3) {
       do_whatever_needs_to_be_done_afterwards();
   }
}
```

Have each 'success' handler in your various ajax calls this `is_done()` function. Once the 'done' count reaches the threshold, then you start up the next stage of things. This'll let you issue all 3 ajax calls at once, without having to run them serialy.

The only downside is that if any of the calls fails for any reason (net.burp, server glitch, etc...) the next stage would never get triggered as the count never reaches the threshold. You might want to add a period check to see if any of the requests stalled/failed and handle that as appropriate.